# create pagination in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to create pagination when I run this I expected to display 4 products in one page but I doesn't happen , it display all products in each categories

```
public ActionResult Category(string name,int? page, int? catId)
        {

            //Declare List Of ProductVM
            List<ProductVM> listOfProductVM;
            //Set Page Number
            var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
            using (Db db = new Db())
            {

                //Get Category ID
                CategoryDTO categoryDTO = db.Categories.Where(x => x.Slug == name).FirstOrDefault();
                 catId = categoryDTO.Id;


                //Initialize The List
                        listOfProductVM = db.Products.ToArray()
                                         .Where(x => x.CategoryId == catId)
                                         .Select(x => new ProductVM(x))
                                         .ToList();


                //Get Category Name
                var productCat = db.Products.Where(x => x.CategoryId == catId).FirstOrDefault();
                ViewBag.CategoryName = productCat.CategoryName;


                //Populate Categories select list
                ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(db.Categories.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
                //set selected category
                ViewBag.SelectedCat = catId.ToString();
            }

            //set pagination
            var onePageOfProducts = listOfProductVM.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 4);
            ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts = onePageOfProducts;
            //return view with list

            return View(listOfProductVM);
        }
```

[This what display's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkzzp.png)

Comment: I answered the same question you asked yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51295726/trying-to-create-pagination-in-asp-net-mvc/51295890#51295890

Comment: it doesn not work

Answer (score 2):

```
return View(onePageOfProducts);
```

instead of

```
return View(listOfProductVM);
```